# Por que é retornado null ao acessar o recurso do managedBean?

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

Estou tendo problemas ao acessar métodos e atributos em um managedbean. Estou utilizando JSF e o servidor Glassfish, já utilizei uma arquitetura semelhante a que estou utilizando porém em um servidor Tomcat.

Gostaria de saber se alguém já teve algum problema do tipo e como fez para resolver, lembrando que por questões de sigilo, omiti alguns nomes de atributos colocando `Object` no lugar.

Mensagem de Erro:

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> type Exception report
>
> messageInternal Server Error
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: /index.xhtml @61,185 value="#{controller.object.nome}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
>       root cause
>
> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @61,185 value="#{controller.object.nome}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
>       root cause
>
> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
>       note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.
>
> GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1

Página Web:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
       xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
       xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
       xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

<h:head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> </meta>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> </meta>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> </meta>
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png"> </link>
    <title>titulo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css"> </link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/styles.css"> </link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/media.css"> </link>

    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <div id="top">
           <div id="logo">
              <a href="#">
                 <img src="assets/img/logo.png" title=""> </img>
             </a>
         </div>
         <div id="menu">
             <ul>
                <li>
                   <a href="#" id="group-menu">
                    <img src="assets/img/menu-list.png" alt="" title=""> </img>
                   </a>

              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="second">
        <div id="right">
            <img src="assets/img/background.png"> </img>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="first">
        <div id="left">

            <h:form class="cmxform" id="formContato" method="post" action="" onsubmit="updateButtonValue()">

                <h:inputText id="fName" value="#{controller.object.nome}" title="Nome: " tabindex="1" required="true" requiredMessage="O Nome é Obrigatório" pt:placeholder="Nome: "/>

                <h:inputText id="fMail" value="#{controller.object.mail}" title="Email: " tabindex="1" required="true" requiredMessage="O E-mail é Obrigatório" pt:placeholder="E-mail: "/>

                <h:inputText id="fPhone" value="#{controller.object.telefone}" title="Telefone: " tabindex="1" required="true" requiredMessage="O Telefone é Obrigatório" pt:placeholder="Telefone: "/>

                <h:inputText id="fInterest" value="#{controller.object.area}" title="Área de Interesse: " tabindex="1" required="true" requiredMessage="A área de Interesse é Obrigatória" pt:placeholder="Área de Interesse: "/>

                <div id="mensagem">

                </div>

                <h:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{controller.salvar()}" ></h:commandButton> 


            </h:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Controller:

```java
package web.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import application.factory.ApplicationFactory;
import application.interfaces.IContatoApplication;
import business.Contato;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Controller implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Object object = new Object();
    private List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

    private IApplication application = ApplicationFactory.getInstance().getApplication();

    public void salvar()
    {   
        Set<String> erros = application.salvar(object);
    }

    public Contato getObject() {
        if(this.object == null)
            this.object = new Object();

        return object;
}

    public void setObject(Object object)
    {
        if(this.object == null)
            this.object = new Object();

        this.object = object;
    }

    public List<Object> getObjects() {
        return objects;
    }

    public void setObjects(List<Object> objects) {
        this.objects = objects;
    }
}
```

Comment: A propriedade nome existe na classe do seu objeto?

Answer (score 0):

Anderson imagino que a classe 'Object' criada por vc tenha todos os atributos desejados com seu getters e setters respectivos, lembrando que o jsf precisa dos metodos acessores, se sim peço que tente algo...

Declare **private Object object;** desse modo mesmo, no managedBean Controller, crie os getters e setters padrões, sem validações como vc fez acima, ficaria assim..

```
public Object getObject(){
  return object;
}

public void setObject(Object object){
  this.object = object;
}
```

agora vem a dica de verdade(kkk) use o metodo init pra instanciar sua classe.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    this.object = new Object();
}
```

acredito que isso vá resolver seu problema.

Comment: Olá Doublas, Obrigado
Consegui resolver o problema, acabei recriando o projeto web do zero, provavelmente era algum arquivo de configuração que não foi criado corretamente